# Two way binding dependences based on enum value in json schema

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a senior were I have to validate the schema for below json data.

`{
    'userId': 123,
    'userType': CUSTOMER 
}`

**Information about JSON:**  Were `userId` is an integer and the `userType` is enum`['Customer','Admin','Guest']`
So the issue is that I want to validate the JSON data from the JSON schema based on :

1. If `userId` is present then `userType` is required.
2. If `userType` `['Customer','Admin']` is present but userId is not then it should not validate the JSON data.
3. But if the `userType` is `['Guest']` then their userId is required.

Here I have achieved point 1  but cannot achieve point 2 and 3 :

```
{
'type': 'object',
  'properties': {
     'user': {
         'type': 'integer',
         'minimum': 0
      },
     'userType': {
         'type': 'string',
         'enum': ['Customer','Admin','Guest'],
      }
   },
   'dependencies': {
       'userId': ['userType']
     }
}
```

Can anyone suggest me json schema solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can solve it with with the property [anyOf](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html) of json Schema, you can add multiple schemas to validate if the `userType` is `Customer` or `Admin` force one schema and if the user type is `Guest` force another one, like this:

```
{
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "user": {
          "type": "integer",
          "minimum": 0
        },
        "userType": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "Customer",
            "Admin"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "user": {
          "type": "integer",
          "minimum": 0
        },
        "userType": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "Guest"
          ]
        },
        "userId": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```