# how to make the json schema flexible enough to handle case sensitive input for enum?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Please refer to this question for the introduction [Two way binding dependences based on enum value in json schema](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59963930/11883120).

Now the case is that if I pass `userType = CUSTOMER` then it doesn't accept the request and in also the case of `userType = customer`.

Can anyone suggest me JSON schema solution for this?

Comment: Do you mean case INsensative? As in, the case is not important?

Comment: Also, it's fine to link to another question, but you should still included all the required info in this question. If the other question for some reason got deleted, this question would then be useless to others. =]

Comment: Hm.... I was going to suggest using a set of `pattern`-ed strings inside a `oneOf` as an alternative to `enum`, but the `pattern` keyword doesn't support regex option switches.  There *may* be some implementations that do, but it's not part of the spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this that isn't awful, but the least awful thing I can think of is to use `pattern` with a regex that includes both cases.

```
{
  "type": "string",
  "anyOf": [
    { "title": "Customer", "pattern": "[Cc][Uu][Ss][Tt][Oo][Mm][Ee][Rr]" },
    { "title": "Admin", "pattern": "[Aa][Dd][Mm][Ii][Nn]" },
  ]
}
```

(The `title` isn't necessary, it's just a nicety for the poor dev who has to read this schema)

Answer (score 0):

This was the exact use case I was trying to solve from the last couple of days, One thing that is clear is schema does not support it directly.

Now if you are using some kind of third-party schema validator tool, they might give you some interface to write you own customize validator (https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema)

There is another way that we can do is preprocess the data before validating it. Let's say in your case userType is the value that is case insensitive and is a set of values only (Customer, customer, CUSTOMER). So I would suggest keeping the ***enum*** value as **customer**[lowercase] and before your JSON is going to schema validator preprocess it to put all the values in the specific key as lowercase value.

The code to preprocess your JSON might look as to below- 
**CONVERT_TO_LOWER_CASE_KEY_SET** - Set of keys that are case insensitive while validation.

```
private JsonObject preProcessInputJsonObject(JsonObject inputJsonBody) {
   inputJsonBody.forEach(innerObject -> {
        if (innerObject.getValue() instanceof String) {
            String value = (String) innerObject.getValue();
            if (value.trim().isEmpty())
                inputJsonBody.putNull(innerObject.getKey());
            else if (CONVERT_TO_LOWER_CASE_KEY_SET.contains(innerObject.getKey()))
                inputJsonBody.put(innerObject.getKey(), value.trim().toLowerCase());
            else
                inputJsonBody.put(innerObject.getKey(), value.trim());
        }
        if (innerObject.getValue() instanceof JsonObject)
            inputJsonBody.put(innerObject.getKey(), preProcessInputJsonObject((JsonObject) innerObject.getValue()));
        if (innerObject.getValue() instanceof JsonArray)
            inputJsonBody.put(innerObject.getKey(), preProcessJsonArray((JsonArray) innerObject.getValue()));
    });
    return inputJsonBody;
}

private JsonArray preProcessJsonArray(JsonArray inputJsonArray) {
    List jsonArrayList = inputJsonArray.copy().getList();
    final int size = jsonArrayList.size();
    for (int iterator = 0; iterator < size; iterator++) {
        if (jsonArrayList.get(iterator) instanceof String) {
            String val = (String) jsonArrayList.get(iterator);
            if (val.trim().isEmpty())
                jsonArrayList.set(iterator, null);
            else
                jsonArrayList.set(iterator, val.trim());
        }
        if (jsonArrayList.get(iterator) instanceof JsonObject)
            jsonArrayList.set(iterator, preProcessInputJsonObject((JsonObject) jsonArrayList.get(iterator)));
        if (jsonArrayList.get(iterator) instanceof JsonArray)
            jsonArrayList.set(iterator, preProcessJsonArray((JsonArray) jsonArrayList.get(iterator)));
    }
    return new JsonArray(jsonArrayList);
}
```

> ***Note:*** I also tried removing extra spaces in the string before validating it.

Hope its helpful, let me know if you see any concern in it.

> One final thing my preprocess data code in java hopefully, you can write something similar in js as well.